# Words for kinds of cargo

Tags: word-request

English has a great range of terms in different areas. I was thinking whether there are names (words,terminology) to speak about different kings of cargo.

For instance, farm animals like cows, sheep, chicken, horses and etc. we can categorise as **livestock**.

- What about equipment and tools?
- What about food, drinks and other beverages and fruit, vegetables?
- What about weaponry, suits, night-vision goggles, helmets, grenades and ammunition?
- What about medicine, vials, bandages and different healing tools?
- What about plants, flowers, different trees?
- What about oxygen, hydrogen, different chemicals and substances?
- What about living organisms and specimens and test subjects?

Is there a word for each category or maybe some grouping words used in transportation?

Comment: You come up with some great questions. :)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of "cargo" to this question. Cows, sheep, chicken, horses, etc., are still *livestock* whether they're being transported 
 or kept on a farm/food production plant. And offhand I can't think of any words to specifically identify particular types of cargo that don't also apply to the same "collection" when ***not*** being transported.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe you are right but maybe there still is a difference.

Comment: If we *farm* cows/sheep/chicken/horses/etc., we call them "livestock". To me, that's a farming-related term, not a transportation term. Judging by 1006a's answer, it looks like there are indeed terms for subcategories of cargo. But, I wouldn't consider "livestock" to be an example ;).

Comment: @EthanKaminski Maybe. I think it means anything that has to do with farm animals. Keeping them, transporting and so on.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd definitely agree that when transporting farm animals, they're still livestock. The way I've seen the word used, that doesn't change until they're killed - which makes some sense, given the "live-" part of the word. I'm just saying it's more related to the farming, is all.

Comment: @EthanKaminski I guess that's why FunbleFingers placed a downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transportation industry, and the agencies that regulate it, have quite a lot of specialized terms for various kinds of things that can be transported. These vary by *how* you want to transport the things, and generally break down fairly broadly based on what kind of handling the things need.

For example, the [Port of Antwerp](http://www.portofantwerp.com/en/types-goods) divides actual ship cargo (the kinds of things that go on cargo ships for transport by sea) into five categories: **Container Cargo** (anything that can fit in a box or container, like TVs and clothing and even meat), **Liquid Bulk** (transported in tankers, like milk or oil), **Dry Bulk** (transported loose in large quantities in the hold, like coal), **Breakbulk** (too big for a container, but delicate-by-shipping-standards, like wind turbine parts or reams of paper; often on pallets), and Ro-ro (short for "roll-on, roll off"; for large, finished vehicles like cars or farm combines, which are literally driven on-and-off the ship).

The [US National Motor Freight Traffic Association](http://www.nmfta.org/pages/nmfc?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) divides freight that is going to be commercially transported into 18 classes, based on what they call "transportability", which includes "density, handling, stowability and liability." These don't (as far as I can tell) include refrigerated or live freight, or any of the "bulk" items above. They also don't seem to break down by what I might consider logical or type categories; for example, the examples given by one shipper for the most expensive class are "Bags of gold dust, ping-pong balls", and the "names" of the classes are all just numbers. You can see [examples of each class here](http://cerasis.com/2013/11/20/freight-class/).

[Wikipedia's Cargo article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo#Shipment_categories) includes various other ways of categorizing cargo and freight, starting with how they are being transported (by sea, air, rail, or road).

From a lay perspective, the categories I've had occasion to consider include things like livestock (because I live in farm country; I haven't shipped them myself), perishables, refrigerated goods, fragile items, hazardous materials (because I have to declare that I'm not shipping them), and liquids.

Answer (score 2):

These are the descriptions I would use. As a general rule, you will want to try and use a description that is:

- Generalized enough that it encompasses everything you've listed
- Specific enough that it is clear what you mean. "Things" would be correct in most cases, but it doesn't particularly reveal *what kind of things* we are talking about.

---

- What about equipment and tools?

**Equipment** seems the most generic description available. Tools are a form of equipment.

- What about food, drinks and other beverages and fruit, vegetables?

**Food** can include both food and drinks, when used in the most general sense of the word.

- What about weaponry, suits, night-vision goggles, helmets, grenades and ammunition?

**[Materiel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/materiel)**. This is an established term (most often used in military context, but according to Merriam Webster it is also correct in a corporate environment).

- What about medicine?

**Medicine**. If your question only lists a single type of item, then that is the correct name to use :)

- What about plants, flowers, different trees and other?

We tend to use **flora**, which comes from [fauna and flora](https://www.reference.com/science/definition-flora-fauna-b97b07a89970b53c). Quite literally, it translates to "animals (fauna) and plants (flora)".

**Plants** would of course also be correct, but flora implies a more general biological definition.

- What about oxygen, hydrogen, different chemicals and substances?

Chemicals would be correct. However, people (wrongly) infer "chemicals" as "dangerous liquid compounds".

Substances would also be correct, but it is a bit vague. It also carries a connotation of being related to drugs. E.g. "substance abuse" inherently refers to alcohol and drugs.

I would use **chemicals**. In my opinion, we should not avoid using the word because some people *wrongly* infer a different meaning.

- What about living organisms and specimens and test subjects?

If you use flora for plants, I would use fauna for animals. However, if all of the cargo can be considered test subjects, I would refer to them as such. "Specimens" is too vague, because saliva swabs are also specimens but by no means an animal.

Note:
"Living organisms" can also include bacteria and microscopic life forms. "Fauna" can't (it is limited to animals).

If you mean animals, use **fauna** (or animals). If you specifically mean lab animals, call them **test subjects** (or lab animals).

Comment: To hitch onto this, **armaments** or **arsenal** can also be used for weaponry. I like materiel best though.

**Produce** is a good term for agricultural and natural food.